# Problems making a developer space on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, php, lamp

Good afternoon, im going to summarize my problem, as a developer i moved to ubuntu i use and i need that my project folder be located on my localhost environment for php to run, reading the Lampp documentation it explains that i must make a "virtual host" in which i put my project files and i open it from the explorer through the ServerName of my "virtualhost" after reading and following the lampp dpcumentation guide, a lot of askubuntu, stackoverflow, and guides on the internet i keep getting or a 403:Forbidden or a 404:Not found, so i come asking help on solving this or any way where i can open my dev files on my IDE(atom) and in my localhost through apache webserver throgh the webexplorer of my choice

thanks in advance, any further information that may be need im going to provide it, only ask

Comment: Welcome! What have you done so far? Did you create the virtualhost in apache configuration? Where are the php files placed?

Comment: as the guide of lampp says, i made my development directory located on /home/myuser/Desktop/Dev/myspace edited the httpd.conf file located on opt/lampp/etc/ removing the "#" from the line "Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf" after this i edited the httpd-vhosts.conf file located on opt/lampp/etc/extra  with this

Comment: "<VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "/home/myuser/Desktop/Dev/"
       ServerName mylocal.localhost
</VirtualHost>" added my virtual host info to "hosts" file located on /etc with: "127.0.0.1           mylocal.localhost" after all this i keep getting or 403 or 404 when i try to reach the "backoffice" folder located inside "mylocal" that contains the file of my project

Answer (score 0):

Well its very hard without knowing what you did and facing problem. But reading your problem what i can tell you that

1. you created folder with Virtualhost : now this folder should have been created by the USER apache and have execute access as well
2. Check using which user you are running your PHP and Apache, ideally Apache should have control on PHP but you might have used the root to create the folder due to which apache is not able to run the PHP
3. now once you validated above you need to revisit the setting in httpd.conf to have correct folder. I NOTICED that your folder and the URL names are different. You have space in name and remember linux flavors are case sensitive too. :)

To me